# Access control allow origin request blocked error while Convert HTML to Image using html2canvas

Tags: image, ionic3, angular6, html2canvas

I have an image and some text ('p' tags) inside an html tag. Using html2canvas I can convert that html element to image. But When i use an image from server , it say **Access control allow origin request blocked error**. I also added allowTaint:true, useCORS:true , but nothing changed. Is there any solution for this? Or any other method ?

Here is my code

**component.ts**

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('invoice-panel'),{allowTaint:true, useCORS:true}).then(canvas => {
  var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
     });
```

**html**

```
    <ion-avatar id="invoice-panel">
      <img [src]="chosenPicture" id="custom-image"/>
      <p *ngFor="let field of arrTextFields" absolute-drag class="newText"><b>{{field.text}}</b></p>
    </ion-avatar>
```

Comment: you are using image from which server. you own that server?

Comment: yes. its our own server

Comment: @Aabid , any idea?

Comment: Its seems like you have not enable `CORS` at your server. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors

Comment: i followed everything according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image, but no use